# Postgres DB stuck in recovery mode

Tags: postgresql

I have an application build with RoR and on Postgres db on separate server (VM with Linux red hat).

I am facing an issue with the db, it suddenly is stuck in the recovery mode, and I can’t access it even from the server console.

The only way is to restart the whole server and again it works fine.

Error details:

> Exception
>   PG::ConnectionBad
>   Error
>   FATAL: the database system is in recovery mode

Please any advise for this issue?

Comment: Not enough information. What does the log file on the database server say? How much disk space does the database server have? How much memory does the database server itself have, and how much memory is allocated in your postgresql.conf?

Comment: You just have to wait until the database is done recovering. You must have crashed it somehow. See the log file for details.